Is it possible to use Metdata Attribute for generic interface implemenations?
For below IMyInterface implementation is it possible to get meta data ienumerable as

IEnumerable<Meta<IMyInterface<IGenericType>>> MetdataList { get; set; }


public interface IMyInterface<in T> where T : IGenericType
{
    public void Test(T generictype);
}

[OperatorMetaData("Screen1")]
public class Screen1 : IMyInterface<GenericType1>
{
    public void Test(GenericType1 generictype);
    { 
        return  ;
    }
}

[OperatorMetaData("Screen2")]
public class Screen2 : IMyInterface<GenericType2>
{
    public void Test(GenericType2 generictype);
    { 
        return  ;
    }
}

I am able retrieve as closed types  IEnumerable<Meta<IMyInterface<GenericType1>>> or  IEnumerable<Meta<IMyInterface<GenericType2>>>  , but not as IGenericType . Please advise.
